# Unable to publish Azure function app v3 C# with .net 5

Tags: c#, azure

I am unable to publish my .net function app. I am using the below configuration and settings:

.net 5 SDK Version: 5.0.300
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker 1.2.0
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core 1.1.0

Getting below error:
Metadata generation failed. Exit code: '-532462766' Error: 'Error generating extension metadata: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The path `PATH\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\bin` does not exist. Unable to generate Azure Functions extensions metadata file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the .targets file of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator, it sets the _FunctionsExtensionsDir to the publish target directory + 'bin'

So if you publish to *project-path*\bin\release\net5.0\publish, it's looking for published output in *project-path*\bin\release\net5.0\publish\bin - you can prove this by doing a replace all in the .targets file replacing ')bin' with ')' and watching it run as expected.

A quick and dirty solution is to build with the -o flag set to where the metadata generator will *expect* the output to be, e.g.

dotnet build *yourproject*.csproj --framework net5.0 -c release -o c:/temp/output/bin -v d
dotnet publish *yourproject*.csproj --framework net5.0 -c release -o c:/temp/output -v d

I'm currently looking into a less hacky way of achieving this, and will post if/when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

*This looks like a bug in Visual Studio 2019.*

**Suggestion:**

1. Record your current version, you can raise a support ticket to confirm with the official.
2. Upgrade your vs2019 to the latest version and try to publish again.

Comment: I am getting similar error in Azure Devops pipeline as well. So I don't think it's only limited to Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @tuhin Devops use same environment with vs2019. So pls contact msft to confirm it.